# React native webview doesnt work on android

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I have simple application react native with expo.

My code is:

```
const html = require('./assets/web/index.html'); 

export default (): any => <WebView source={html} />;
```

Problem is that web page is loaded as pure html on android device. On IOS device it is working perfectly.

I am using react-native-webview

```
11.23.0
```

Any tips how can I fix my issue?

Google, SO and githu issues